# Using clonezilla to mirror hard drives to be used on different system?

Tags: clonezilla

I've cloned my system hard disk to another hard disk using boo-table [Clonzilla](http://clonezilla.org/clonezilla-usage/clonezilla-live-usage.php) USB because I don't want to do a clean installation of Ubuntu on a second system now my second system is running fine.I want to know that Is this a safe procedure to escape fresh installation of Ubuntu on a second machine,Will it create some problem in future updates and upgrades.

Comment: What are the specs on both machines?

Comment: I don't think it's a good idea (Without the full specs it's anyone's guess) but you can try it

Comment: The first installation has undoubtedly got some customizations in a variety of config files for the hardware it was installed on. A direct copy is likely to raise a host of unexpected and unpredictable problems.